# how to index a dynamic page on google that has no public link to it?

Tags: laravel, indexing, seo, vue.js, googlebot

I came accorss a very big question, i'm currently making a web app. Here's an overview :

Public pages :

```
/home
/login
/post/:id (so each dynamic page must be public and indexed)
```

Private pages

```
/posts
/post/:id/comments
/and-other-private-urls
```

As you can see the `/posts` page which would have the full list of each posts and it's url is private, therefore, how can i get google to know about my posts single pages since i have no page indexing all of them ?

From what i understand the googlebot will come to my `/home` and lookup for links, index them, and do the same thing for each link he finds.

If i have no page indexing each **post** created on my web app, is there a way to notify google of a new page created or something ?

Technologies :
- frontend : VueJS framework
- backend : Lumen framework (by Laravel team)

PS : i dont want the `/posts` page to be public that's why i have this problem, and of course i could generate a **sitemap** that would be fed each time a post is created but the thing is a sitemap generation would slow my server each time a post is created or deleted... since i'd have to regenerate all of it to be sync

PS 1 : i'm looking for optimized options

Answer (score 0):

I can't understand the reason for what you ask, but you can try to make an RSS feed with all your posts and push the URL of RSS to Google via addURL page.

Also, it would be better if your / has the link to RSS feed somewhere. I mean, if it is not- it would be strange for Google to track some URL that nobody links to.

Comment: let me give you an example, on facebook your feed is not public, but on your feed you can see "public pages" posts, or "public events" posts. These posts are indexed on google but there's no page which lists all the pages or event on fb, which means, fb found a way, to tell google to index all those pages. I guess it's a sitemap or something

Comment: I would go with sitemap then.